# Cypress - Need data from multiple pages on different URLs

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress

I'm new to cypress. My scenario is as follows:

1) Go to a test page.

2) Initiate an init script which interacts with the server and creates some session.

3) Go the backoffice

4) See that the new session appears in the table

The sessionId is received from the test page. When I initiate the session, I get the sessionId as a response (it is part of my test).

The problem is, that when I go to the backoffice (by using `cy.visit`) the whole cypress session resets, and I lose the sessionId.

I tried to use global variables and aliases, but to no avail.

Is there a way to pass the sessionId variable to the backoffice test?

Here's my code:

```
describe('Session init', () => {
let requestBody;
let responseBody;
let sessionId;
  describe('Init the session in the client', () => {
    before(() => {
      cy.server();
      cy.route({
        method: 'POST',
        url: initUrl,
        onRequest: (xhr) => {
          requestBody = xhr.request.body;
        },
        onResponse: (xhr) => {
          responseBody = xhr.response.body;
        }
      }).as('init');
      visitTestPage(); // uses cy.visit to go to the test page - also initiates a new session
    });

    it('should send POST init request', () => {
      cy.wait('@init').then(() => {
        expect(requestBody).to.contain.keys(
          keysToExpectInRequest
        );
      });
    });

    it('should receive an init response', () => {
      cy.wrap(responseBody.session).as('session');
      sessionId = responseBody.session;
      expect(responseBody).to.contain.keys(
        keysToExpectInResponse
      );
    });
  });

  describe('Verify a session was created in backoffice', () => {
    before(() => {
      backofficeLogin(); // using cy.server and cy.visit, using premade jwt to avoid UI login
    });

    it('should see a live session with the id from the init', () => {
      cy.get('.session-row').then((sessions) => {
        expect(session[0].id).toEqual(sessionId); // expect the latest session created to be with the id of the session created in the test page
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you save the sessionId in the cookie you can use this:

```
cy.wrap(responseBody.session).as('session');
sessionId = responseBody.session;
cy.setCookie('sessionId', sessionId);
```

[doc](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/setcookie.html#Syntax)

But it is not recommended, because each test you perform must be independent of each other : [doc](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Having-tests-rely-on-the-state-of-previous-tests)

Comment: Thanks. Where is this cookie saved? How can it be used after the second visit command (the backofficeLogin function)?

Comment: This cookie is save in cookie of your page, you can see your cookie with chrome or firefox element inspector (touch F12) and in application tab. You can save sessionId in fixture file and get this for the setCookie(). Check documentation ;)

Comment: ***"But it is not recommended,..."*** - you could avoid coupling between tests by completing the code above in the `before()`. Then the first test simply retrieves the cookie and asserts it has a value. (Also not forgetting to clear the cookie in an `after()`).

Comment: The cookie is saved in the test page's domain, which is different than the backoffice domain - hence, I need to use an iframe to retrieve the cookie from the test page domain while in the back office domain.

I've done that already - was hopping for a less hacky solution (I'm used to nightwatch and webdriverio, in which this is a breeze) :)

Regarding the `not recommended` part - there are some use cases the cypress team did not bring into account (like testing the effect of a complex SDK).